# Unable to use editRow with jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

The line `grid.editRow(id, true);` - is giving error.

> `uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'editRow'`

How can this be fixed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/GridData/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Votes', 'Title'],
            colModel: [
      { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 40, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'Votes', index: 'Votes', width: 40, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
      { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 400, align: 'left'}],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '',
            caption: 'My first grid',
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                var grid = $("#list");                    
                grid.editRow(id, true);
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>  
...
<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't posted the whole HTML code which you use, so I'll have to guess. The most common reason for the problem which you describe could be one of these two:

1. You included code like `$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;` before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. So only "new API" can be used. In other words you should replace the code `grid.editRow(id, true)` to the code `grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, true)`.
2. You downloaded and used `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` which doesn't include the "Inline Editing" module. To verify this you can open `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` in a text editor and search for `grid.inlinedit.js` string in the comment which is at the begining of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` file. The list of all jqGrid modules included in the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` file is after the text "* Modules: ". You need to [download jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) with "Inline Editing" module.